# Qt Debugger Freezes With OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, debugging, freeze

[image]

If I don't include `cv::Mat test;` then the debugger works fine. The inclusion of that 1 line, for some reason, kills the Qt debugger.

Symptoms:

- The variables view forever loads
- The coded program freezes - you cannot stop, start or step anything
- The editor functions normally
- Breakpoints become unremovable until you stop debugging mode
- After 40 seconds you're given the option to stop the debugger, inferring that it may be in an infinite loop - this (or closing Qt) is the only way to stop the debugger
- Running the code in runtime works as expected
- Running the code without breakpoints works as expected

I'm not doing anything fancy (to my knowledge), so the settings should be the defaults on installation.

Version info:

- Qt Creator 4.2.1
- Based on Qt 5.8.0 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit)
- From revision 7071b61e02

I can't work with this anymore! Its slowed the debugging process down to a crawl just finding where the bugs are. The problem seems to be new, having only just started a few days ago. What's going on? How can I bring the debugger back to life without reinstalling Qt? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do your Qt app debug on Windows with Visual Studio and it has very good own debugger. That is easy even without having the project being created for VS. And with Qt Creator you can just run it without debug and see the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not OpenCV only. I have the same problem on Windows. the Windows Debugger (WinDbg) is horribly bad. Many times it freezes like you're describing and takes forever with that irritating waiting spinner. It's not even possible to view the value of a `boost::filesystem::path`. Some times it doesn't even show variables that are there (like `this` sometimes), and when I expand it in Qt Creator, they appear empty.

Therefore, I decided not to do hardcore debugging on Windows anymore. What I do, is do very shallow debugging on Windows, and hardcore debugging I do on Linux, with gcc and gdb. I have a virtual machine (VM Ware) that I use for this.

Comment: Not WinDbg which is powerful yet hard to use but CDB. That one you integrate with Qt Creator on Windows. WinDbg is a professional tool.

Comment: @AlexanderVX Probably. I'm not sure. Maybe I'm wrong in that. But I'm having the exact same symptoms that guy described that I gave up on Windows debugging.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Hey, thanks for the reply. I'm _really_ hoping that's not the solution given the symptoms are new... Its not "technically" solving the problem either, but I also accept that it is a valid workaround. As such, I'll wait a while before accepting it =p

Comment: @user I'm also interested in such a solution. Let's see if it exists.

Comment: Debugging Windows app with Linux? I do mostly Linux code now and will never think that that is a way except very simple and portable code.

Comment: @Alex all my windows code is portable to Linux. I never write code that doesn't compile on Linux. Worst case, I create abstractions of behavior. The reason is that all profiling tools are easily available on Linux, such as memory analyzers. It's a pain in the axe to have them on Windows, and most of them are not for free.